# How i can get topic number after I post in SMF board

Tags: php, curl

Hellow everybody.
I have a problem to get topic number after post SMF board.
I use Curl for posting, Now i user Curl to get link and preg_match_all to get topic number but not work because some web Curl can't get link.
So i want to know idea or another way to solve to get topic number with php

Thank you all.

Comment: Better to show your code here and explain more your query!

Comment: Use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION and then call curl_getinfo and look at the effective url?

Comment: $curl = curl_init('http://am2012driverdownload.com/index.php?board=26.0'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  
$result = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);

preg_match_all('/\<a[^\?]+\?([^\"]+)\"\s*\>test\<\/a\>/', $result, $match);

print_r($match);